# Can a modal verb like 会 go with the aspect particle 过？

Tags: grammar

Is there any situation in which 会 serves as a verb "to be able to/to know how to" and 过 is attached to it as an aspect particle? If not, why not?

Any example I find of 会+过 is clearly using 会 to express probability and 过 as a verb: "一切都会过去的".  Here, 过 is *not* used as an aspect particle, so it's not an example of what I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

[会 + V] indicates the verb has not been carried out

[V + 过] indicates the verb had been carried out,

Example:

我**会去**美国 - I **will go** to America (O)

我**去过**美国 - I **had visited** America (O)

我**会去过**美国 - I **will be had visited** America (X)

如果我去过北极的话我**会见过**北极熊 - If I had been to the North Pole, I **would have seen** polar bears (O)

我**会去**北极**看过**北极熊 - I **will go** to the North Pole and **had seen** polar bears (X)

> [会 + V + 过] only work when 会 means 'would' and not 'will'

Comment: The correct way to say "我会去过美国" is " 我会(v)过去(v)美国" - "I'll go over to the U.S."

Comment: @r13 "我会去过美国" is an example of incorrect usage of 会 and 过 together, notice the (X) mark. 过 in 我会过去美国 is a verb, not an aspect marker. Please read the question more thoroughly

Comment: Yes, I know you have marked it as "incorrect", thus I made the "correct sentence" in my comment to show the pattern 会(v) + 过去(v) - "will go over to". I did not mean you were wrong though.

Comment: @TangHo, what about with another modal verb? 可以，for example? How would you express "I had the experience of being able to"? 可以过 doesn't seem right...

Answer (score 1):

There is no “会 + 过” structure when 会 is used to express “be able to do something”

I will Try to offer some explanation from a native speaker’s angle.
In Chinese, 会 is used to describe skills or knowledge acquired after learning and practicing. So in our logic, you will not forget everything. There is no need to create a structure as “会+过+ do something” .In Chinese, we often say sentences like “你到底会还是不会？” “会就是会，不会就是不会”

Hope this can help.